# Install R cairo package after installing cairo via conda

Tags: r, cairo, conda

I'm trying to install the Cairo package for R. I don't have admin rights for the server so I installed Cairo via the conda package manager `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda cairo`. I have compiled R from source in my home directory. 
I have tried to add the following to my bashrc:

```
export CAIRO_LIBS=-L${HOME}/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/lib/cairo/
export CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I${HOME}/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/include/cairo/
```

When I try `install.packages('Cairo')`, I get the following error:

```
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/N/u/jfreimer/Mason/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/include/cairo/
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... yes
checking cairo.h presence... yes
checking for cairo.h... yes
checking for PNG support in Cairo... yes
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-L/N/u/jfreimer/Mason/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/lib/cairo/
checking for library containing deflate... -lz
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/N/home/j/f/jfreimer/Mason/R/lib64/R/library/Cairo’
```

Anaconda has an R package of cairo (https://anaconda.org/r/r-cairo) so all of the dependencies that I need should be installable via conda. However, I am trying to use the standalone R that I installed and not conda R as I have had trouble with other packages in conda R. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions

Comment: Did you read the `config.log` file? What does it say?

Comment: I searched within the R folder and can't find a file called `config.log`, where is it kept?

Comment: Conda has commercial support. Maybe rely on that instead?  Most of us here use the CRAN repo network instead.

Comment: I'm trying to install the Cairo package off of CRAN, but I need R to see the Cairo libraries installed in linux first.

Comment: Just checking the installation of the package on my Ubuntu, I see `CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12` and `CAIRO_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng12 -lz -lXrender -lcairo -lXext -lX11`. Quite different from yours.

Comment: First, try something like `export CAIRO_LIBS=-lcairo` and 
`export CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I${HOME}/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/include/cairo/` to see if it compiles.

Comment: I changed those settings and it still wouldn't install.

Comment: configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/N/u/jfreimer/Mason/miniconda/pkgs/cairo-1.12.18-6/include/cairo/
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... yes
checking cairo.h presence... yes
checking for cairo.h... yes
checking for PNG support in Cairo... yes
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-lcairo
checking for library containing deflate... no
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.

Comment: You have `checking for library containing deflate... no`. You need `zlib` installed on your computer.

Comment: I have zlib installed here: `~/miniconda/pkgs/zlib-1.2.8-0`. How do I get R to see it?

Comment: I cannot test it further. Maybe try with `ZLIB_CFLAGS`. Or add the path to zlib in `CAIRO_CFLAGS` and add `-lz` in `CAIRO_LIBS`. No warranty.

Comment: Any success in installation?

Comment: Eventually talked to the server admin. These were the things I needed to specify if anyone else runs into this problem. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/N/soft/rhel6/cairo/1.14.2/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/N/soft/rhel6/cairo/1.14.2/bin
export CAIRO_INCLUDE_PATH=/N/soft/rhel6/cairo/1.14.2/include/cairo
export CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/N/soft/rhel6/cairo/1.14.2/include/cairo
export CAIRO_LIBS='-L/N/soft/rhel6/cairo/1.14.2/lib -lcairo'`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
R -e "install.packages('cairo')" --configure-vars=
"CAIRO_CFLAGS=/PATH_TO_CAIRO/include/cairo;
 CAIRO_LIBS=/PATH_TO_CAIRO/lib/cairo"
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.  I solved it by simply uninstalling and re-installing.

Open up R in the terminal console:

```bash
R
```

Uninstall `Cairo`

```
remove.packages("Cairo")
```

Re-install:

```
install.packages("Cairo")
```